# Using jest and react native: "Cannot find module 'ErrorUtils' from 'index.js'"

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm just starting out using Jest with React Native.  We've already built out a bunch of our apps.  I'm trying to just run the default tests provided by React Native and am getting an error:

```
Cannot find module 'ErrorUtils' from 'index.js'
```

for each of `__tests__/index.ios.js` and `__tests__/android.ios.js`.  `ErrorUtils` is a standard React Native module that I'm importing in my top-level index.js file, which is in turn imported from the above two test files.

Answer (score 0):

In the RN 63, deleting any references to `ErrorUtils` worked fine.  (There was an unnecessary line mocking it in the `jestSetup` file.)